# Meaning of !! in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, version, symbols

I was looking for a way of detecting the current browser using javascript code and came across an answer mentioned [here at the same forum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/709194).

**My question is:** What is the meaning of `!!` (double exclamation symbol).

The value `!!document.documentMode` is returning a boolean value depending on whether the current browser is IE or not and the value `document.documentMode` returns the version of the IE browser.

I want to understand what `!!` actually signifies.

Answer (score 1):

> So !! is not an operator, it's just the ! operator twice.

---

> !oObject  //Inverted boolean
>
> !!oObject //Non inverted boolean so true boolean representation

[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)